NotFoundError: Could not find directory D:/Języki programowania/Python/Projekty/Pneumonia_detection/chest_xray/chest_xray/train
I don't know reason that error above appears, although I have directory as in n title.
D:/Języki programowania/Python/Projekty/Pneumonia_detection/chest_xray/chest_xray/train
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory # type: ignore

import os
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# Importing dataset
import zipfile

dataset = zipfile.ZipFile("D:/Downloads/archive.zip", 'r')
dataset.extractall()
dataset.close()

# Read the image data
path = 'D:/Downloads/chest_xray/chest_xray/train'

path = 'D:/Języki programowania/Python/Projekty/Pneumonia_Detection_CNN/kaggle/chest_xray/chest_xray/train'

classes = os.listdir(path)
print(classes)

# Define directories for X-ray Images
PNEUMONIA_dir = os.path.join(path + '/' + 'PNEUMONIA')
NORMAL_dir = os.path.join(path + '/' + 'NORMAL')

# Create list of files names in each directory
pneumonia_names = os.listdir(PNEUMONIA_dir)
normal_names = os.listdir(NORMAL_dir)

print("There is", len(pneumonia_names), "images of pneumonia infected in training dataset")
print("There is", len(normal_names), "normal images in training dataset")

# Plot the Pneumonia infected Chest X-Ray images
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(24, 12)

pic_index = 210

pneumonia_images = [os.path.join(PNEUMONIA_dir, fname)
                    for fname in pneumonia_names[pic_index-8:pic_index]]
for i, img_path in enumerate(pneumonia_images):
    sp = plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1)
    sp.axis('Off')
    
    img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
    plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()

# Plot the Normal Chest X-Ray Images
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(24, 12)

pic_index = 210

normal_images = [os.path.join(NORMAL_dir, fname)
                 for fname in normal_names[pic_index-8:pic_index]]
for i, img_path in enumerate(normal_images):
    sp = plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1)
    sp.axis('Off')
    
    img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
    plt.imshow(img)
    
plt.show() 


base_dir = 'D:/Języki programowania/Python/Projekty/Pneumonia_detection/chest_xray/chest_xray'
Train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir + '/' + 'train')
if not os.path.exists(Train_dir):
    os.mkdir(Train_dir)
Test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir + '/' +  'test')
if not os.path.exists(Test_dir):
    os.mkdir(Test_dir)
Val_dir = os.path.join(base_dir + '/' + 'val')
if not os.path.exists(Val_dir):
    os.mkdir(Val_dir)


Train = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    Train_dir,
    labels = "inferred",
    label_mode = "categorical",
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size = (256, 256)
)
Test = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    Test_dir,
    labels = "inferred",
    label_mode = "categorical",
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size = (256, 256)
)
Validation = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    Val_dir,
    labels = "inferred",
    label_mode = "categorical",
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size = (256, 256)
)

I expect result as below:
Found 5216 files belonging to 2 classes.
Found 624 files belonging to 2 classes.
Found 16 files belonging to 2 classes.

We can't know which files exist on your system, but when the computer tells you a file doesn't exist, it's nearly always telling the truth. A typical beginner mistake is supplying the wrong directory name. If you are a Windows user, dragging the file to a CMD window will reveal its correct path; similar mechanisms are often available in other GUIs, too.

Are you running the script on your pc or are you using an online interpreter? The second one cannot easily access your local pc.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

if you use os.path.join() then you don't have to use + and / but os.path.join(base_dir, 'test'). And if you want to use + and /then you don't needos.path.join() -Test_dir = base_dir + '/' +  'test'- but it is safer to useos.path.join()instead of+and/`

maybe first check current working directory using os.getcwd() - it may show if you run in correct place. You can also check os.listdir('D:/') to check if you really have folder D:/Języki programowania , and later you can check os.listdir('D:/Języki programowania'), etc. I don't know how today but long time ago systems had problem with native letters like Polish ę (and with spaces) so we never used ąęśćńółżź

sometimes file or folder may have space at the end of name - and it is not visible in Windows Explorer but this can make problem because path need this space too.
